# how to pass dynamic params to html onclick written in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

```js
function populateProductsToHomepage() {
  let divToPopulate = '';
  const {products} = apiResponse;
  products.forEach((product, i) => {
    if (product.type === 'featured') {
      const stringifiedProduct = JSON.stringify(product);
      divToPopulate += `<div
      class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-1 best"
      id="${product._id}"
      onclick="storeIdInLocalStorage(this)"
    >
      <a href="singleproduct.html" class="text-decoration-none text-dark">
        <div class="collection-img">
          <img src="${product.images[0]}" class="" width="100%" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <p class="fw-bold text-capitalize my-1 text-start">${product.name}</p>
          <p class="fw-normal text-end">PKR ${product.price}</p>
          <p class="fw-light text-start">${product.shortDescription}</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" onclick="addToCart(${stringifiedProduct})">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>`;
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('homepageProductsContainer').innerHTML =
    divToPopulate;
}
```

issue is with passing object in param on onclick function
getting unexpected end of input
I tried a lot of methods but still failed

Comment: You can solve this by not using `onclick` attributes. Put the custom value in a `data` attribute on the element, then use a single unobtrusive event handler (delegated if necessary due to your dynamic content) to handle the clicks on that element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you refer to an example?

Comment: @AbdulHananAsif Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @Lixas I can't get a specific product I clicked on using data

Comment: @karthik unexpected end of input

Comment: what is the value you are getting in **stringifiedProduct**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Example for the [comment from Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76153138/how-to-pass-dynamic-params-to-html-onclick-written-in-javascript#comment134298521_76153138)*

Add the product id as data attribute to the div, remove the onclick and add a class that we use for the click handler:

```
      divToPopulate += `<div
      class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-1 best product-click"
      data-product-id="${product._id}"
    >
```

Now we add a click handler referencing the new class (but bound to the document, as products can be added dynamically) that fetches the id from the data attribute:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  const target = e.target.closest(".product-click");

  if(target){
    const productId = target.dataset.productId;
    storeIdInLocalStorage(productId);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!